# Finite difference: move forwards or backwards?

Tags: programming, finite-difference-method

In finite differences for the black scholes method, you move backwards in time, since of course you know the prices at time $t = T$, and then you iterate until you get to time $t = 0$.

However, why then in this code does the time move forwards? Here, *cur_t* is current time, and as you can see, he iterates and each time moves *cut_r* **forwards** by *dt*.
[image]

Entire code can be found here:
https://www.quantstart.com/articles/C-Explicit-Euler-Finite-Difference-Method-for-Black-Scholes

Is this a mistake in the code?

Answer (score 5):

They have written the equation to be solved as 
$$
-\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + r S \frac{\partial C}{\partial S} + ... = 0
$$
instead of the more usual 
$$
\frac{\partial C}{\partial t} + r S \frac{\partial C}{\partial S} + ... = 0
$$
This means that in their setup $t$ represents the **time to maturity**, that is $t = T - \text{time}$. So they start from $t = 0$ where the option value is equal to its payoff, and they move forward in time to maturity until reaching $t = T$ which corresponds to $\text{time} = 0$ .